# How to log dotnet test output in junit format

Tags: c#, .net-5, dotnet-cli

`dotnet test` uses trx output by default. I am using [trx2junit](https://github.com/gfoidl/trx2junit) to convert it to junit, but this complicates CI setup.

Is it possible to output test report in junit format directly from dotnet test?

Comment: It's unlikely there will be a setting to get C# to output a Java format., which is probably why someone wrote trx2junit.

Comment: @Neil but maybe there is option to integrate it directly with `dotnet test` using some msbuild magic instead of doing it manually in CI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install the NuGet package to your test project:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="JunitXml.TestLogger" Version="3.0.110" />
   ```
2. Run the following command to output the test results in JUnit XML format:

   ```
   dotnet test --logger:junit
   ```

More info here:

- https://github.com/spekt/junit.testlogger
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1911

Answer (score 0):

anyone knows how to install junit logger (if it is possible ?) on system that can be enumerated via this command ?

- vstest.console /ListLoggers

I find the need to  install package on csproj quite crappy